# how does jackson derive type for deserialization in "Could not resolve type id 'foo' into a subtype

Tags: java, spring, serialization, redis, jackson

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a group of objects including sub-classes with jackson. I am using the JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes annotations. It works fine working with DynamoDB but I'm also trying to cache using Redis (via spring's redis components). It writes to redis fine, but am getting the following error when trying to retrieve from redis :

Could not resolve type id 'LinkedTreeMap' into a subtype of [simple type, myBaseClass] : known type ids = [myBaseClass, sub-class1, sub-class1...]
... through reference chain....->[collection of MyBaseClass]->java.util.ArrayList[0]...

I think the LinkedTreeMap is in the gson library. We have a pretty large maven project and gson is in there due to other library dependencies, but I don't see how or why it's being pulled into this usage. It looks like it's deriving this class based on the structure of the json. The Json it's trying to deserialize looks like it is a list instead of a map.

So where is this LinkedTreeMap coming from?

We are also using the following ObjectMapper for redis :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS);
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

We are also using a custom serializer which implements RedisSerializer.  You'd think this might be the first place to look for issues like this, but it is pretty minimal, and seems to be necessary when you autowire RedisTemplate with Spring @Bean.

Comment: Can you give examples of the classes you are trying to work with, and how you are deserializing them. Did you manage to create a test that replicates this behaviour?

Comment: after more testing it looks like it may have to do with the JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes annotations, because it is actually a serialization problem; the LinkedTreeMap is being written to redis as the value for the property that I was using to determine which sub-class to use